# HTML5, CSS Transitions & JS Triggers

Tags: javascript, css, html, transition

To give a basic idea of what I hope to accomplish;

I currently have a site live at:
http://shiinachi.com

As it is, the body element is changed using javascript when clicking between the home and email tab.

However, I hope to redo this. I aim to have the width of the body expand when a button is clicked, so the body "drops down" to show the menu in question.

I have experimented using an onload function to trigger a css class;

> function bodyloaderS() { classList.add("body-loader")

The css of the body is set to a width of 0 by default, then I attempted to use the body-loader class in question to adjust the width.

> body-section.body-loader{ width: 745px; }

I then called the transition onload to test it. However...
[The results were less than successful.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgmTJ.png)
Is there a better way I can go about doing this?

Edit:
Here's a dump of the code being used

Body tag;

```
<div id="body-section" onload="bodyloaderS(document.body-section)">
    <h1>Home</h1>
     <p>Hello.<br><br>Temp</p>                  </div>
```

Relevant CSS;

```
#body-section{
position: relative;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
height: 350px;
width: 0px;
transition: width 2s;
border-color: #ffffff;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 1px 3px 3px;
border-radius: 3px 9px 3px 0px;
top: -752px;
left: 325px;
background-color: #222222;
}

#body-section.body-loader{
width: 745px;
}
```

The script in use;

```
    <script>
function bodyloaderS() { classList.add("body-loader") 
}
    </script>
```

Comment: maye if you post the minimal code to let us reproduce the code and see what you have tried so far, then we can help yout better

Comment: You want a transition effect on the body maybe when a button is clicked, if I understand right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also add a target element in your function it will work, e.g.

```
function bodyloaderS() {
  document.querySelector('#body-section').classList.add("body-loader");
}
```

---

Also, you might want to consider start using event listeners instead

```
var thebody = document.querySelector('#body-section');
thebody.addEventListener('load', function() {
  this.classList.add("body-loader");
})
```

---

*Updated based on a comment and a question edit*

The `onload` event doesn't work on `div` elements.

Here is a suggestion using a `DOMContentLoaded` listener

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var thebody = document.querySelector('#body-section');
  thebody.classList.add("body-loader");
  
});
```

```css
#body-section {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 0px;
  transition: width 2s;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 9px 3px 0px;
  /*
  top: -752px;
  left: 325px;
  background-color: #222222;
  */
}

#body-section.body-loader {
  width: 745px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body-section">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Hello.<br><br>Temp</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the quick reply.
I'm afraid to say both ideas yielded no different results. 

I've attempted to check for errors using chrome's dev mode, but there  are no errors dumped.

Comment: Thanks! That event listener made it work straight away.